# Flipping view causes back button to appear on navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have explicitly set the navigation bar's back button to be hidden by the following method -

```
[[self navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES]
```

This works fine when I enter this view from a view (which is flip-able, it's a map view). The back button does not appear if I enter the view without flipping the previous view (the map view). However, if I enter this view after flipping the map view, a back button appears. And this button does not function at all on tapping it.

I have tried `setLeftBarItem:nil` method, but even then it appears (and doesn't function)!

Anyone have a solution to this really odd problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```

OR

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton: YES animated: YES];
```

Comment: Nope. This doesn't do anything at all for the problem that I am having. As I mentioned, the back button appears only when I flip the previous view.

Comment: @ Joel Joseph where are you adding this? in the mapView?

Comment: No. The first view has two buttons. When I click on the first button, it takes me to the view where I don't need the back button (and it doesn't in this scenario). On click of the second button, it flips the view and shows a map view. Now you can flip back and click on the first button. This time, the back button appears.